# Microsoft OpenAI Curie deployment not working for the JSONL file

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai

I am trying to generate deployment using below JSONL data. Model is successful, but deployment is failing without any reasons. Please advise.

```
{"prompt":"what is abakaas?","completion":" ABAKAAS is a platform star that drives RABACSA on a star's mooon for 243 days."}
{"prompt":"what is bdbasdbasd?","completion":" BDBASDBASD is the formula used to capture comet's tail praschts in real time."}
{"prompt":"what is dsdfsdfe?","completion":" DSDFSDFE is the theory behind writing Torums in spanish in 1930s."}
```

I was expecting to use the playground to test the deployment with "CURIE" model.

**Deployment screenshot:**

[image]

**Model screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Deployment using below JSONL data. The model is successful, but deployment is failing without any reason.

The error you can see is whether you are passing the wrong jsonl file or you are deploying more than once.

You can follow this [MS-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/fine-tuning?pivots=programming-language-studio#deploy-a-customized-model) to create the customized model and deploy the model.

I used the below sample JSON file to create a model.

```
{"prompt":"Company: BHFF insurance\nProduct: allround insurance\nAd:One stop shop for all your insurance needs!\nSupported:", "completion":" yes"}
{"prompt":"Company: Loft conversion specialists\nProduct: -\nAd:Straight teeth in weeks!\nSupported:", "completion":" no"}
```

**Model:**

[image]

**Deployments:**

[image]

**Playground:**

[image]

> **Note:**
> Only one deployment is permitted for a customized model. An error message is displayed if you select an already-deployed customized model.

**Reference:**
[How to prepare a dataset for custom model training - Azure OpenAI Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/prepare-dataset#case-study-is-the-model-making-untrue-statements)

Comment: Can you try deploying model using JSON file from my question? I am clear with the process and had reviewed the document. Also, Azure does not let you pick a model thats already deployed, so that is probably not the reason for failure. I am thinking if its something to do with the JSONL file, or some other configuration.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with jsonL file only.